Efficient way to update comment like statuses after user login in a React application
I’m building a blog application in React where each blog displays a list of comments. Each comment includes:

Like count (total number of likes for the comment)
Like status (whether the currently logged-in user has liked the comment)

There are two scenarios I’m considering:
When the user is not logged in:
Since there’s no logged-in user, the like status for all comments would be false.
Should I:

Fetch only the comments and their like counts in a single API call(like status will be false for all as user is not logged in)?
Fetch comments first and then make additional calls to fetch like status of each comment using useEffect?

When the user logs in:
After login, the UI needs to reflect the correct like status for each comment based on the logged-in user. Should I:

Refetch all comments, their like counts, and the like status for the logged-in user in one big API call?
Fetch only the like status for the logged-in user in a separate API call for each comment using useEffect and update the previously fetched comments?

Considerations:
The number of comments per blog can vary and I want to ensure the solution is efficient, minimizes backend load, and provides a smooth user experience.
I’m also using a relational database where comments and likes have a one-to-many relationship.
Which approach would you recommend for each scenario, and why? Are there alternative patterns or best practices I should consider for optimizing these API calls?
Thank you in advance for sharing your insights!
